# Developer friendly WiFi SDHC card

Tags: wifi, memory-card

There are a few SDHC Cards with WiFi, but I find it difficult to understand what they can actually do, and even harder to find out how they do it.

I would like a card that is "developer friendly" and lets me access it through an API of some sort. I know that the FlashAir card has a developers site, but I find the product information lacking for the competition.

An example of a simple task could be to automatically download all RAW files from the SDHC card and convert them to JPEG on the computer.

Things that would be interesting to know are:

- Can the card be accessed through open protocols, or do you need a proprietary library?
- If you need a lib, which platforms are supported?
- Are there licenses or any other restrictions on developing and distributing apps for the card?
- What capabilities does or doesn't the card have? Read, write, access without user interaction through some kind of pairing for example.

Comment: Josef, it would be nice to be more specific. What requirements do you have?

Comment: I am interested in the capabilities so that I might be able to innovate from there. I edited the question a little. Copying files from the card, without requiring authentication from a human being each time, would be the minimum requirement.